# ReactJS: Updating parent application state from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently trying to learn React by making a simple application that grabs data from the openFEC API.

I currently have two components defined in my application, a SearchBar and a Candidate component.  This is what my App.js currently looks like:

```
class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = { candidate: [], searchTerm: '' }
    }

    render() {
      return (
         <div className="App">
          <SearchBar />
          <Candidate candidate={this.state.candidate}/>
         </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**Problem:** I need to update the Candidate component based on the data I receive from the API response.  However, I'm making the API call in the SearchBar component and have no way of updating the candidate state defined in the App component.

Should I make the API call in the App component instead? If not, is there a way to send the data I get back from the SearchBar component into my App component?

Comment: When there is suck kind of peer dependency between components, I would advise you to look into redux also.

Comment: @PriyankKapadia I would not say this situation needs Redux; besides OP has not even grasped basics of object communication in React yet, so Redux is a bit early; fyi (https://github.com/petehunt/react-howto)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way (without making API call from `App`).

```
class App extends Component { 
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = { candidate: [], searchTerm: '' }
      this.onDataReceived = this.onDataReceived.bind(this);
    }

    onDataReceived(data){
       this.setState({ candidate: data });
    }
    render() {
      return (
         <div className="App">
          <SearchBar onDataReceived={this.onDataReceived}/>
          <Candidate candidate={this.state.candidate}/>
         </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Roughly what happens here is:

- You can see how I passed a function as a props to the `SearchBar` component via `onDataReceived` props.
- You can invoke that function from within `SearchBar` component (e.g. make API call and call function passed as props with API results).
- Invoking `onDataReceived` function will trigger `setState`
- Calling `setState` will call render and now the `Candidate` component will receive more recent data from state.

[More](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Since the onDataReceived function is being passed down via props from App to SearchBar, I can update the state from SearchBar to App? Doesn't App and SearchBar each have their own local states?

Comment: @JonathanCho Yeah they do but from SearchBar you can call a function which is defined inside App (because you passed it as props) which on the other hand updates state which belongs to App.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is have the API call in your App Component, and pass that function down as a prop to your SearchBar Component. Your parent component (in this case, App) should be holding on to all of the relevant information and passing down to it's children what they need.

It should look something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  ... 
  handleSearch(term) {
    //handle fetch here 
    .then(res => this.setState({candidate: res})
  }
  render() {
    <div className="App">
      <SearchBar handleSearch={this.handleSearch}/>
      <Candidate candidate={this.state.candidate}/>
     </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah after a lot of googling, it seems like this is the best way to do this.  So does that mean all the JSX in my SearchBar component needs to be moved into the App component? Thanks for the input btw.

Comment: No, not necessarily. I mean, you could move all the JSX into App, but that kind of defeats the purpose of React and having separate Components. Having functions that get passed down to it's children as props and called in the child (in SearchBar, you'd call `this.props.handleSearch('search term')` is a really common pattern in React and pretty much the only way to pass info between siblings. It's a little weird but kind of nice - the parents has most of the really important functions and info, the children are much simpler and just do what they need to do.

Answer (score 1):

In this way, you can achieve this

```
 class App extends Component { 
        constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state = { candidate: [], searchTerm: '' }
          this.triggerSearch=this.triggerSearch.bind(this);
        }

       triggerSearch(searchTerm){
            this.setState({searchTerm})
        }

        render() {
          return (
             <div className="App">
              <SearchBar trigerSearch=
             {(searchTerm)=>this.triggerSearch(searchTerm)} />
              <Candidate candidate={this.state.candidate}/>
             </div>
          );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```